# I want to align/match two unequal columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

so I have these two dataframes of different lengths and I want to align them if there is a match. If there is no match, I want a NA or NULL.

So it would look like this:
df1:

```
ABCC1  
ADCY2  
ADNP2 
ADRA1B  
ALMS1   
AOC1
```

and df2:

```
ABCC1  
ABCC1  
ADCY2  
ADNP2  
ADRA1B
```

I want the results to be this:

```
    ABCC1  ABCC1
    NA     ABCC1
    ADCY2  ADCY2
    ADNP2  ADNP2
    ADRA1B ADRA1B
    ALMS1  NA
    AOC1   NA
```

I have used merge but I didn't work for me. Probably because I don't know how to properly use the "by" option.

Comment: How exactly didn't the merge function work? What did you run exactly? What are the column names of your data.frame? The more important parameter is probably `all.x=TRUE` rather than `by=`.

Comment: If I do `all.x=TRUE` then it would for instance repeat ABCC1 for the whole length of d1. So the dimensions would be length(df1)*length(df2) instead of the length of the largest df. I ran `merge(df1,df2, all=T,by=intersect(names(df1),names(df2)))` and `merge(df1,df2, by.x="V1", by.y="V2")` (so V1 and V2 are the column names) and many more but none of them worked. Only the `by=intersect` gives me two columns in the mergedf but also with the length df1*df2 instead of the df with the largest length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package. We can create columns for merging. `ID1` is the same as the original column, while `ID2` is the index number of each `ID1`. After that, we can use `full_merge` to create the desired output.

```
library(dplyr)

dat1_2 <- dat1 %>%
  mutate(ID1 = V1) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

dat2_2 <- dat2 %>% 
  mutate(ID1 = V1) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

dat3 <- full_join(dat1_2, dat2_2, by = c("ID1", "ID2")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("ID")) %>%
  arrange(V1.y)

dat3
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   V1.x   V1.y  
#   <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 ABCC1  ABCC1 
# 2 NA     ABCC1 
# 3 ADCY2  ADCY2 
# 4 ADNP2  ADNP2 
# 5 ADRA1B ADRA1B
# 6 ALMS1  NA    
# 7 AOC1   NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "ABCC1  
ADCY2  
                   ADNP2 
                   ADRA1B  
                   ALMS1   
                   AOC1",
                   header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat2 <- read.table(text = "ABCC1  
ABCC1  
ADCY2  
ADNP2  
ADRA1B",
                   header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry I'm new, didn't know how to haha